# show jQuery Pop up after Adding User to Database

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET MVC and I have the following problem.
After the admin created a User I want to show a success pop up using jQuery.
This is the code that I have written:

```
            <button id="show-dialog" type="submit" class="btn blue ">
                Create
                <i class="icon-plus"></i>
            </button>

            <div id="dialog">
                <p>
                    The User is saved in DB
                </p>
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('#dialog').dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        resizable: true, 
                        dialogClass: 'ui-dialog-blue',
                        show: {
                            effect: "blind",
                            duration: 500
                        },
                        hide: {
                            effect: "clip",
                            duration: 500
                        }
                    });
                    $("#show-dialog").button().click(function () {
                        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

The Problem is, that after I click on the button the user is not saved into the database.
Please forgive my poor english

**==============EDIT================================================================**

After removing the return false the data is saved correctly. But now the pop-up only shows up about 1 second and I am redirected to another page cause by the method in my controller. 
Should I just implement Thread.sleep() or what would be the best solution?

Comment: So your saying you're execution doesn't reach the controller or the form isn't actually submitted? Do you want to submit the form normally or via ajax?

Comment: Yes the pop would only show for a split second that's why I had suggested using ajax. Have you tried the suggested ajax solution? That way your pop up will show after the data is successfully saved and not prior (which would actually make more sense). Do you really want to use a pop up? Otherwise you could always redirect to a success page instead. @Superbyte

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Ben
Because I am pretty new to this stuff I don't actually know what to put in here:

$.post( 'your-route',

I am on the Create View of the User and when someone adds a new User the Controller will redirect him to the Index.cshtml.
So should I put '/User/Index'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try removing the

```
return false;
```

line in the click function. That should allow you to submit the form on button click but you won't see your dialog message when the page refreshes.

Alternatively you could use an ajax call to post your form. Something like this:

```
$("#show-dialog").button().click(function () {
    $.post( 'your-route', $('form').serialize(), function(data) {
         $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    })        
});
```